# Run CMD command without displaying it?

Tags: c#

I have created a Process to run command in CMD.

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c apktool d app.apk");
process.WaitForExit();
```

How can I run this command without displaying actual CMD window?

Comment: `process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih looks like that could be an "answer"...

Comment: CMD window is still displaying.

Comment: @crashmstr Thought so too, but as he said it didn't work

Comment: What would be even better is if you executed the process directly rather than trying to run command prompt. You will still have the same issue of showing a prompt most likely, but it is redundant to do both, I think. It could very well be that apktool is launching a window on its own, hence why the standard fixes are not working. Running it directly should fix that.

Comment: Try add `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`

Comment: @orglce Is that you whole code? Maybe you set `UseShellExecute` or ??`Username/Password`

Comment: We should read the code, he is starting the process when initializing the object, so the properties won't be recognized. Shame on us :/

Answer (score 11):

You can use the WindowsStyle-Property to `indicate whether the process is started in a window that is maximized, minimized, normal (neither maximized nor minimized), or not visible`

```
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```

**Source:** 
Property:[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) 
Enumartion: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx)

And change your code to this, becaeuse you started the process when initializing the object, so the properties (who got set after starting the process) won't be recognized.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c apktool d app.apk";
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This is no different than @sino 's answer. How did this work?

Comment: @gunr2171 `He is starting the process when initializing the object, so the properties (who got set after starting the process)  won't be recognized.`

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues with your program, as pointed out in the various comments and answers. I tried to address all of them here.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "apktool";

//join the arguments with a space, this allows you to set "app.apk" to a variable
psi.Arguments = String.Join(" ", "d", "app.apk");

//leave it to the application, not the OS to launch the file
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

//choose to not create a window
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

//set the window's style to 'hidden'
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

The main issues:

- using `cmd /c` when not necessary
- starting the app without setting the properties for hiding it

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
     proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: that impossible , write your code here, or update your question

Comment: @orglce did you try `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` with @sino code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Also, [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score -1):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;
```

Comment: Adding the extra stuff, from wherever that is copied from, makes this answer kind of confusing, especially with no explanation of what the code is doing.

Comment: A little explanation in your post goes a long way.

Comment: @Dimo I can't force you to do it, I was just offering some advice for improving your answer. That's what the site is about - the community working together to solve problems like this. It isn't about spoon-feeding, it is about providing well-written, helpful, clear, and complete answers.

Comment: Some [relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers) meta discussion.  Keep in mind that we don't just write answers for OP's context, but also future visitors (with varying levels of competency) with the same question.